# How to give an alias of a column in result set in prisma?

Tags: prisma

How to give an alias of a column in result set in prisma?

I need to give an alias for a field in query result.
How will I do that in Prisma?

Any help will be appreciated!!!!!

Comment: Are you looking for the @map operator?
https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#map

Answer (score 0):

If the result doesn't need to update the schema, you could potentially use the extensions functionality to add a 'result' column to your query with a custom name ([Docs here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/client-extensions/result)).

Alternatively, use [queryRaw](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access) to write raw SQL in a prisma query, and use `SELECT <existing_column> AS <new_alias>` (or an equivalent).